# is it possible to use k-means on a folium map? - iPython

Tags: k-means, folium

I have a map plotted with a list of coordinates

```
newmap = folium.Map(location=[52.667989, -1.464582], zoom_start=6, tiles='Stamen Terrain' )

for coord in new_latlonl:
    la, lo = coord[0], coord[1]
    newmap.polygon_marker(location=[la, lo], fill_color='#43d9de', radius=8)

newmap.create_map(path='newmap.html')
```

Is it possible to use k-means clustering on this?

Comment: It all depends on the library you're using, but I don't know of any Kmeans libraries that are specifically made for folium maps. Is there a reason you don't want to use a more general-use clustering library? 

It is absolutely possible if you extract the coordinates first into a numpy array

Comment: Thanks for your answer - could you explain more of what you mean? - How exactly it would work with a numpy array and maybe an example? thanks. Currently the coordinates are in a list.
I am still very new to this!

Comment: People doing clustering in python will mostly use numpy arrays. Numpy is a library for numerical computing in Python. It's really fast because it links to Fortran libraries.

I have never worked with folium but if you can get you coordinates into a plain of list of lists then you can do:

import numpy as np
yourNumpyArray = np.asarray(yourPlainList)

and then use compatible clustering libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will give it a try... however I have another dumb question, How do I get my coordinate list into a list of lists? - I have tried a couple of things but can't work it out.